# Replace one line with another with Laravel or PHP

Tags: php, string, file, laravel, replace

So I have text file that content looks, for example, as folows:

> Name: 'John',
>
> Surname: 'Doe',
>
> Age: 35

But **I don't know for sure if the current surname is Doe**, anything could be generated there.

And **I need to replace this surname with another one**. So I need to somehow open the file, find the place I need (I know for sure that it starts with `Surname: '` and ends with `',`, and I need to replace string between these two substrings, whatever it was before, without breaking the file structure (losing line breaks and so on; the actual file is pretty long, so adding \n manually is not an option).

So far I've tried this

```
$content = file_get_contents('text.txt');
$search = "/[^Surname: '](.*)[^',]/";
$replace = 'Smith';
$content = preg_replace($search,$replace,$content);
file_put_contents('text.txt', $content);
```

But it replaces almost everything with 'Smith', because the combination of `',` is pretty common in this file, and also it turns the entire file into one line.

So what could I do to solve my problem? Would highly appreciate any possible help!

UPD: str_replace could be what I need, but first then I need to retrieve the whole line `Surname: 'Doe',` from the file to get the current surname.

Comment: `[^Surname]` will match a line which doesn't contain any of the characters `S u r n a m e :  '`

Comment: Is php the right tool to use for this? If you are no *nix you could use sed, or even if you need to start it from the web you could call a bash script using sed http://brunolinux.com/02-The_Terminal/Find_and%20Replace_with_Sed.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the regex `/^Surname: '.*',$/m` based on your description and replace it with `Surname: 'Smith',`.

Code:

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('text.txt');
$search = "/^Surname: '.*',$/m";
$replace = "Surname: 'Smith',";
$content = preg_replace($search, $replace, $content);
file_put_contents('text.txt', $content);
```

Demo:

```
$ cat text.txt
Name: 'John',
Surname: 'Doe',
Age: 35
$ php a.php
$ cat text.txt
Name: 'John',
Surname: 'Smith',
Age: 35
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex should help:

```
"/Surname: '(.*)'/"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = "Name: 'John',

Surname: 'Doe',

Age: 35";

$search = "/Surname:\s+'(.*?)',/is";
$replace = 'Surname: \'Smith\',';
$content = preg_replace($search, $replace, $text);
echo $content;
```